# Modal dialog stacking in Vue 3

Tags: vue.js, dialog, modal-dialog, vuejs3, vue-component

I'm trying to make a modal dialog system for my Vue 3 application.
I'd like to have the possibility that multiple modal dialogs can be stacked over each other.
My idea is to make a generic `DialogComponent`, with a `<slot>` for the content and a `<slot>` for the footer, to be able to place buttons or something else there.

This is my `DialogComponent`

```
<template>
    <div v-if="isOpen" ref="dialogElem" class="dialog">
        <header class="dlg-header">
            <div class="dlg-header-content">
                {{ headerText }}
            </div>
            <div class="dlg-close">
                <button @click="handleCloseClick" class="dlg-close-btn">
                    &#215;
                </button>
            </div>
        </header>
        <div class="dlg-content">
            <slot name="contentSlot"></slot>
            <footer class="dlg-footer">
                <slot name="footerSlot"></slot>
            </footer>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        components: { },
        props: {
            isOpen: Boolean,
            headerText: String
        },
        expose: ['open', 'close'],
        data() {
            return {
            }
        },
        methods: {
            handleCloseClick() {
                this.close();
            },
            open() {
                this.$store.commit('showOverlay');
                this.$nextTick(function () {
                    this.adaptPosition();
                });
            },
            close() {
                this.$store.commit('hideOverlay');
            },
            adaptPosition()
            {
                const dialogRect = this.$refs.dialogElem.getBoundingClientRect();
                let top = (window.innerHeight / 2) - (dialogRect.height / 2);
                let left = (window.innerWidth / 2) - (dialogRect.width / 2);
                this.$refs.dialogElem.style.top = top + 'px';
                this.$refs.dialogElem.style.left = left + 'px';
            }
        }
    }
</script>

<style>
.dialog {
    position: absolute;
    top: 200px; /* default for example */
    left: 500px; /* default */
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 150px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    background: #fff;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 3;
}
.dlg-header {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: stretch;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #d0d0d0;
}
.dlg-header-content {
    flex: 1;
    padding: 15px;
}
.dlg-close { display: flex; }
.dlg-close-btn {
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    line-height: 16px;
    text-align: center;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background: none;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #444;
    vertical-align: middle;
    transition: background-color .2s, color .2s;
}
.dlg-close-btn:hover { background-color: #d0d0d0; color: #000; }
.dlg-close-btn:active { box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.30); }
.dlg-content { flex: 1; padding: 15px; }
.dlg-footer { margin: 15px 0 0 0; }
</style>
```

But, when any dialog is open, there must be a semi-transparent backdrop/overlay over the whole screen.
I cannot create a backdrop for each dialog. Because when there would be multiple dialogs open stacked on each other, the backdrops would be stacked too. When the backdrops would have an opacity of, say 0.5, and another one is stacked over it, the part of the screen that is still visible, would be getting darker and darker by the stacked backdrops.

JSFiddle link to clarify what I mean: https://jsfiddle.net/dgotkpze/

I think I have to manage dialogs in a single place in my application, like in `App.vue`. My plan is to create one single backdrop element in the `App` template, and put all currently opened dialogs in that backdrop element using v-if.
The `App` component keeps a data variable like `dialogs` that I can use for the v-if iteration in the backdrop element. The `App` component can listen to an event bus. That way I can open dialogs from literally everywhene in the application.

Here's my App.vue:

```
<template>

    <div class="app-layout">

        <div class="app-main-layout">

            <!-- app content -->

        </div>

        <div v-if="dialogs.length > 0" class="backdrop">
            <DialogComponent v-for="(dialog, index) in dialogs" :key="index"
                           :isOpen="true"
                    :headerText="{dialog.headerText}">
                
                <!-- Problem with slots... -->
                <template v-slot:contentSlot>
                    <!-- How to get desired content (a component) here? I've only got the dialog variable. Can I do something like dialog.content which is a component on its own? -->
                </template>
                
                <template v-slot:footerSlot>
                    <!-- Same problem here -->
                </template>
                
            </DialogComponent>
        </div>

    </div>

</template>

<script>
    import EventBus from '@/eventbus.js';
    import DialogComponent from './components/DialogComponent.vue'

    export default {
        name: 'App',
        components: {
            DialogComponent
        },
        data() {
            return {
                dialogs: []
            }
        },
        mounted() {
            EventBus.listen('dialogOpen', (dataDescribingDialog) => {
                console.log(data);
                this.dialogs.push(dataDescribingDialog);
            });
        },
        methods: {
            //...
        }
    }
</script>

<style>
    .backdrop {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        z-index: 999999;
        background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    }
</style>
```

When I want to open a dialog from some 'application view' component:

```
<template>
    
    <!-- Application view things -->
    <h1>Write your text</h1>
    <textarea></textarea>
    
    <button @click="saveFile">Save as...</button>
    
    <template ref="fileSaveContentTemplate">
        File name:
        <input type="text" />
    </template>
    
    <template ref="fileSaveFooterTemplate">
        <button>Save</button>
    </template>
    
</template>
// Somewhere in a 'application view' component.

export default {
    import EventBus from '@/eventbus.js';
    methods: {
        saveFile() {
            EventBus.emit('dialogOpen', {
             headerText: "Save file as...", 
             content: ????, // maybe this.$refs.fileSaveContentTemplate ???
             footerContent: ??? // this.$refs.fileSaveFooterTemplate ???
            });
        }
    }
}
```

As you maybe understand now, I'm having difficulties with transferring content from a random place to the `<DialogComponent>` in `App.vue`. I'd like to be able to open a dialog from any component in my application, and put in any desired component in that dialog as its content / footer content. Dialogs must be generic/reusable. I don't know how to achieve this.

Another (meybe better) idea is to make a dialog component for each different use case of a dialog. Like `FileSelectDialog.vue`, `FileSaveDialog.vue`, `ConfirmDialog.vue`, etc.
In that specialized dialog (like `FileSaveDialog`) I could use the generic `DialogComponent` in the template, and put my content in that dialog in the template:

```
<!-- Component FileSaveDialog.vue -->
<template>
    <DialogComponent headerText="Save file as...">
        <template v-slot:contentSlot>
            <label>File name</label>
            <input type="text" />
        </template>
        <template v-slot:footerSlot>
            <button>Save</button>
            <button>Cancel</button>
        </template>
    </DialogComponent>
</template>
```

I think this second approach is much cleaner. But now when I want to use (open) my `FileSaveDialog` from somewhere, I have to 'communicate' that `FileSaveDialog` component to my `App`, so it can render it there (in the backdrop container). But then I get stuck again with this part in `App.vue`:

```
<div v-if="dialogs.length > 0" class="backdrop">
    
    <!-- Now I cannot just use the DialogComponent tag statically in the template, because each item in the
        dialogs array is a specific (specialized) component, like FileSaveDialog -->
    <SomeSpecificDialogComponent v-for="(dialog, index) in dialogs" :key="index"
                   :isOpen="true"> 
        
    </SomeSpecificDialogComponent>
</div>
```

I think this is a very common thing. How can I do this?